# Eclipse Main Menu (Top level) Show Action: MainMenuEvent

Tags: eclipse, events, view, menu, eclipse-plugin

I searched Google And Asked In eclipse forum but still confused how to do this simple thing:
I got example for SWT :

```
public class MenuActionListenerShow {
```

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);

```
Listener showListener = new Listener() {
  public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    Menu menu = (Menu) event.widget;
    MenuItem item = menu.getParentItem();
    if (item != null) {
      System.out.println(item.getText());

    }
  }
};

Menu menuBar = new Menu(shell, SWT.BAR);
shell.setMenuBar(menuBar);
MenuItem fileItem = new MenuItem(menuBar, SWT.CASCADE);
fileItem.setText("File");
MenuItem editItem = new MenuItem(menuBar, SWT.CASCADE);
editItem.setText("Edit");
Menu fileMenu = new Menu(shell, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
fileMenu.addListener(SWT.Show, showListener);
fileItem.setMenu(fileMenu);

shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
  if (!display.readAndDispatch())
    display.sleep();
}
display.dispose();
```

}

}

I am looking to do the same thing but to Main Menu (e.g File/Search/Edit) .
I have plug-in with view that my purpose is when File/Edit/Search.... (Menus) pressed/shown/cascaded , a text with the Menu name shows in my view. 
Is it possible or its not allowed to get the API references of Main Menu of Eclipse?
It will be great for some tips.

THanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it althought it isn't as easy as it might look like. The main menu in eclipse is very dynamic. Submenus are created lazy for example, or a switch of an editor might bring new menus on top. You have to ensure to register/unregister your listeners all the time.

If you create a view you can use the given parent composite to get the main menu and register your listeners. But as I said, you have to ensure to register/unregister the listeners all the time or you will get memory leaks, multiple registered listeners ...

Here is an example view the does the registering. It does not do the tracking of new items/disappearing items (do this as homework ;) ).

```
public class ViewPart1 extends ViewPart {
    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        Shell shell = parent.getParent().getShell();
        Menu menu = shell.getMenuBar();
        addListeners(menu);
    }

    private void addListeners(Menu menu) {
        menu.addListener(SWT.Show, showListener);
        for (MenuItem item : menu.getItems()) {
            Menu subMenu = item.getMenu();
            if (subMenu != null) {
                addListeners(subMenu);
            }
        }
    }

    Listener showListener = new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            Menu menu = (Menu) event.widget;
            MenuItem item = menu.getParentItem();
            if (item != null) {
                System.out.println(item.getText());
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
    }
}
```